# Getting NULL when data is present in column

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I am currently writing a secure login for a VB.net application I am creating. The login verification is being handled via a stored procedure on the SQL Server (2008 R2). I need the procedure to verify username and password. Then kick back the login message (@responsemessage) and the (@AccessLevel) so that I can determine which form opens next (Admin or User) in my VB script.

Here is the procedure I have so far

```
AS
BEGIN
  -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
  -- interfering with SELECT statements.
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @UUID INT
DECLARE @ResponseMessage NVARCHAR(250)     
DECLARE @AccessLevel VARCHAR(1)
BEGIN 
IF (SELECT UUID from logins where Username=@pUsername AND PassHash=HASHBYTES('MD5', @pPassword))


        SET @UUID=(Select UUID FROM logins where Username=@pUsername AND PassHash=HASHBYTES('MD5', @pPassword))             
        SET @AccessLevel=(Select SecLevel FROM logins where Username=@pUsername AND PassHash=HASHBYTES('MD5', @pPassword))      

        SET @ResponseMessage=(SELECT statdesc from statuscodes where StatID='2')


 End
  ELSE
        Begin       
        SET @ResponseMessage=(SELECT statdesc from statuscodes where StatID='3') 
        Select @ResponseMessage as 'Result', @AccessLevel as 'AccessLevel'
```

END
Select @ResponseMessage as 'Result', @AccessLevel as 'AccessLevel'
End

When I enter a Username and Password that is in the logins table, I get the correct login message but my AccessLevel column comes back as NULL. The variables are being fed in from a VB.net winform I built.

Comment: What happens when you run the `SELECT` for the access level directly in SQL Server?  Do you get a value back?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Yes I do get the proper value back when I run the select query. But when run as part of the stored procedure. It kicks back null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your IF statement is wrong in two ways:

Firstly you should be using IF EXISTS, and secondly you aren't wrapping the 3 SET statements in a BEGIN END block.

This results in the first SET not getting executed becuase the IF is not True, and the 2nd/3rd SETs are always executed because they aren't controlled by the IF.

You should change your SQL to

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT UUID from logins where Username=@pUsername AND PassHash=HASHBYTES('MD5', @pPassword)) BEGIN


        SELECT @UUID= UUID, @AccessLevel= SecLevel  FROM logins where Username=@pUsername AND PassHash=HASHBYTES('MD5', @pPassword)

        SET @ResponseMessage=(SELECT statdesc from statuscodes where StatID='2')


 End
```

You can also combine the first two SETs into a single select since they are targetting the same record in the database.

Comment: You could also potentially throw out the IF, by just executing `SELECT @UUID= UUID, @AccessLevel= SecLevel  FROM logins where Username=@pUsername AND PassHash=HASHBYTES('MD5', @pPassword)` and then checking to see if you get values in the variables. If they're NULL then the're no match. This would reduce your code to a single SELECT statement, although it's probably not much of a gain.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @UUID INT
    DECLARE @ResponseMessage NVARCHAR(250)     
    DECLARE @AccessLevel VARCHAR(1)

    IF EXISTS(SELECT UUID from logins where Username=@pUsername AND PassHash=HASHBYTES('MD5', @pPassword))

    BEGIN
        SET @UUID=(Select UUID FROM logins where Username=@pUsername AND PassHash=HASHBYTES('MD5', @pPassword))             
        SET @AccessLevel=(Select SecLevel FROM logins where Username=@pUsername AND PassHash=HASHBYTES('MD5', @pPassword))      

        SET @ResponseMessage=(SELECT statdesc from statuscodes where StatID='2')
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
            SET @ResponseMessage=(SELECT statdesc from statuscodes where StatID='3') 
    END

    SELECT @ResponseMessage as 'Result', @AccessLevel as 'AccessLevel' 
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone for all the replies.

While all of those blocks of code were helpful. I found the root cause of the issue.

My stored procedure for creating the logins was setting the @pPassword as CHAR(20)

My stored procedure for verifying the login was setting the @pPassword as VARCHAR(40).

So the hash created was factoring in the extra characters from the CHAR designation. While the verification procedure was trimming off the extra characters before hashing to verify. Being it was missing the extra characters, the hashes were different and causing the script to drop to the failure message.